# Error when compiling PHP with openssl: recompile with -fPIC

Tags: php, linux, configuration, compilation, openssl

I did compiled the openssl using the commands below:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl -fPIC
make
make test
make install
```

So, when I'm trying to compile the php I have the follow error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libbz2.a(bzlib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `BZ2_crc32Table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libbz2.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: ** [libphp5.la] Erro 1

This error occours when I running the command for to configure the PHP:
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs  --with-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin --with-mysql --with-mysqli --enable-mbstring --with-mcrypt=/usr/lib/libmcrypt.so --with-pdo-mysql --enable-opcache --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-zlib --with-bz2=/usr/local/bzip2  --with-zlib --with-curl && make clean && make && make install && service apache2 restart
```

Like when I compiled the openssl I needed to use the -fPIC parameter, I belive that the problem are related with the openssl.

I'm using Debian.

Comment: does 'config' accept the fpic argument directly? fpic is a gcc flag. if config isn't passing that in to gcc, then you're NOT compiling in PIC mode.

Comment: @MarcB How to know this?

Comment: libbz2.a and bzlib.o are not openssl libs. Try to substitue -fPIC when you trying compile the PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If your system is `64bit`, when you compile `openssl`, '`-m64`' would be added to the compile flag, just open `Makefile` of `openssl`, remove all '`-m64`', then

```
make & make install
```

and then go back to php source dir, make would be ok!